# Perfect square or not?

Tags: algorithm, perfect-square

This is a code to check if a number is perfect square or not. Why does it work ?

```
static bool IsSquare(int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (; ; )
    {
        if (n < 0)
            return false;
        if (n == 0)
            return true;
        n -= i;
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because all perfect squares are sums of consecutive odd numbers:

- 1 = 1
- 4 = 1 + 3
- 9 = 1 + 3 + 5
- 16 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7

and so on. Your program attempts to subtract consecutive odd numbers from `n`, and see if it drops to zero or goes negative.

You can make an informal proof of this by drawing squares with sides of `{1,2,3,4,...}` and observe that constructing a square `k+1` from square `k` requires adding `2k+1` unit squares.

Comment: Thanks :) I never knew about this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I just saw that.. did it!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - and yes we can easily prove it by drawing squares.. here is a video explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gC5eVRatOQ

Comment: @user1386320: of course you _can_ learn this at school. School programs are different per country and adapted differently by teachers, so it may be bad luck.